# Short story - small group of telepathic children searching for Santa Claus' workshops

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, teleportation, santa-claus

I read this short story 4-5 years ago but don't know date of writing, or the author. A small group of children scattered around the world, with telepathic and other super-normal powers decide to hunt for Santa Claus' workshops. Along the way they discover all the world's nuclear weapon silos, and teleport all the fissile material from them either to to the bottom of the oceans or out into space. Very entertaining story, so I'd be most grateful for being pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [*Christmas Treason*,](https://www.sectorgeneral.com/shortstories/christmastreason.html) a short story by James White.

It was first published in *The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction* in the Christmas time edition in 1961 (it was in the January, 1962 edition which came out in December of 1961.)

I have it here in a copy of *Asimov Presents the Great SF Stories - 1962* published in 1992.

The children are from all over the Earth.  They are telepathic among themselves though not with other people.  Besides the telepathy, they also have other abilities.  Some can teleport and others can move objects (telekenesis.)

The oldest of the kids is six years old.  They are trying to figure out how Christmas works, and are following clues about Santa Claus.  They find that the adults all agree that Santa Claus live far up North in the Arctic.

One of the boys has the ability to teleport to a real place like whatever place he imagines, so they describe what Santa's house or workshop could look like and he tries to teleport there.

In trying to find Santa, they locate American and Soviet missile bases.

Their childish imagination leads them to believe that Santa has been kidnapped and that the missiles are to deliver the presents.  They also find that somebody has loaded the rockets with bad stuff.

The boys who can teleport and the girls who can do telekenisis work together to remove the bombs and put toys (from toy stores) in their place in the missiles.

At the end they get all the rockets launched to deliver the presents on Christmas day.

Missiles hit major cities all over the USA and the Soviet Union, causing damage but not killing anyone.

The end result is the start of "Peace on Earth."

The kids wake up after all the excitement to find that Santa Claus visited while they were all asleep.

It's a cute story.  Not bad, not great, just cute.

Comment: Of course it is, thank you! I'd got a copy of James Whites' "The White Papers" 5 or 6 months ago; of the few books of his I hadn't read yet, and where I first saw this story. How could I forget it... I enjoyed the clever pun in the title nearly as much as the story itself. Thanks again!

Comment: So, only boys can teleport and girls can telekinese?